# Asp.net multiple files upload using Ajax

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-core

I am trying to upload multiple files but using ajax , i am facing two specific problems

first(java script problem):
how to loop through input files and put it inside array of files before sending (by ajax)

second:(c# problem):
how to receive the files in backend (what type of data should i use as parameter data type?)

here is my failed attempt:

html code:

```
<input type="file" name="file" accept=".pdf,.docx,.doc" class="drop-zone__input" multiple>
```

jQuery:

```
  <script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#addreply').click(

            function () {

                {
                    var files = $("#fileInput").get(0).files;
                    var fileData = new FormData();

                    for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
                        fileData.append("fileInput", files[i]);
                    }
                            var formData = new FormData();
                    //formData.append('file', $("[name='file']")[0].files[0]); // myFile is the input type="file" control
                    formData.append('reply', $("[name='reply']").val()); // myFile is the input type="file" control
                    formData.append('mid', @Model.Message.Id); // myFile is the input type="file" control
                    formData.append('files', fileData); // myFile is the input type="file" control

                    var _url = '@Url.Action("AddReplyDetails", "Messages")';
                        $.ajax({
                            url: _url,
                            type: 'POST',
                            data: formData,
                            processData: false,  // tell jQuery not to process the data
                            contentType: false,  // tell jQuery not to set contentType
                            success: function (result) {
                                //$('#file').val("")
                                $("#ssss").load(window.location + " #ssss").find('.rm').last().hide().fadeIn();
                                $('html, body').animate({
                                    scrollTop: $('.rm').last().offset().top
                                }, 2500);
                            },
                            error: function (jqXHR) {
                            },
                            complete: function (jqXHR, status) {
                            }

                        });

                }
                $("#reply").val('')

                });
    });
    </script>
```

backend:

```
   public async Task<IActionResult> AddReplyDetails(List<IFormFile> files,IFormFile file, string reply, int mid)
    {

        string filesnames="";
        foreach (var item in files)
        {
           filesnames +=await UserFile.UploadeNewFileAsync("", item, _environment.WebRootPath, Properties.Resources.Files);
            filesnames += ",";
        }
        Message message = _context.Messages.SingleOrDefault(m => m.Id == mid);
        message.LastActivitydate = DateTime.Now;
        message.IsRead = false;
        _context.Messages.Update(message);
        _context.MessageReplies.Add(new MessageReply
        {
            ApplicationUserId = _userManager.GetUserId(User),
            Content = reply.Replace("\n", "<br/>"),
            Attachment = filesnames,
            MessageId = mid,
            DateOfRecord = DateTime.Now,
            IsRead = false,
            IsDeleted = false,
            IsReported = false,
        });
        _context.SaveChanges();

        return RedirectToAction("Details", "Messages", new { id = mid });
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Important thing to note is the parameter names

```cs
AddReplyDetails(List<IFormFile> files, IFormFile file, string reply, int mid)
```

so you have `files`, `file`, `reply`, `mid`

if you are posting `FormData` (which you will need if you are posting files)

You want to try to match the parameter names

```js
var formData = new FormData();
formData.append('file', $("[name='file']")[0].files[0]);
formData.append('reply', $("[name='reply']").val());
formData.append('mid', @Model.Message.Id);
for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
    formData.append('files',files[i]);
}
```

and when posting include the content type header

```
headers: {'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'}
```

I would reccomend wrapping the above in a form object.

```cs
public class MyForm {
   public List<IFormFile> Files {get;set;} 
   public IFormFile File {get;set;}
   public string Reply {get;set;}
   public int Mid {get;set;}
}
// note the name of the parameter
AddReplyDetails([FromForm] MyForm form)
```

and then change `FormData`

```js
var formData = new FormData();
formData.append('form.file', $("[name='file']")[0].files[0]);
formData.append('form.reply', $("[name='reply']").val());
formData.append('form.mid', @Model.Message.Id);
for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
    formData.append('form.files',files[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check on this link:
https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/da55bf/multiple-files-upload-using-jquery-ajax-and-jqueryui-progres

upload multiple files at once and save them in a local folder with a progressbar

I did a few modifications on the above working example

1. added additional parameters to formdata

   formData.append("LoanNo", $jq("#LoanNo").html());
   formData.append("MemberNo", $jq("#MemberNo").html());
2. and on the server side

   HttpFileCollection UploadedFilesCollection = context.Request.Files;
   string loanno = context.Request["LoanNo"].ToString();
   string memberno = context.Request["MemberNo"].ToString();

Comment: I did a few modifications on the above working example 1. added additional parameters to formdata `formData.append("LoanNo", $jq("#LoanNo").html());
                    formData.append("MemberNo", $jq("#MemberNo").html());` and on the server side `HttpFileCollection UploadedFilesCollection = context.Request.Files;
                string loanno = context.Request["LoanNo"].ToString();
                string memberno = context.Request["MemberNo"].ToString();`